# What is the accepted method of renewing interest in a question?

Tags: discussion, bump

(I think the term might be "bumping").

In real estate here, a property that has failed to sell after a long time on the market will sometimes be taken off the market briefly and then put back on.  This seems to generate a wave of renewed interest.

Is there a way of doing this within the stack overflow protocol?

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214085/where-should-i-locate-my-git-repositories-for-projects-that-share-common-librari#32214236) that hasn't yet had an acceptable answer.  Should I just be patient, or strip out the specific point that hasn't been addressed and use it to form the basis of another question?  Or is this where bounties come into play?

Comment: yes this is the main use of bounties

Comment: Bounties are the appropriate way to go to call attention to a question, but it's only been up for a day, so bounties aren't yet available.  Just be patient

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is the Help Center page on setting Bounties.

Comment: You edit the title of your question and prefix it with "REDUCED PRICE!!!"

Comment: That is not "a" question, those are three questions. Three questions of which one or more are likely duplicates. The next time I would ask one question at a time, that makes the answers easier to formulate and verify. Lower the barrier, so to speak.

Comment: Related FAQ on meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taking it down and re-posting the same is generally seen as abusive (even more so without taking the first version down).

Just bumping it to bump it, the same.

The options you have are:

1. Enhancing the question significantly (and thus *incidentally* also bumping it).
2. Making it known to those able and willing to answer it using off-site channels they approve of for doing so.
3. Posting a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: Thanks, please elaborate on point 2

Comment: @rossmcm  If I understand point 2 correctly, it's something like tweeting to all your programmer followers that you have a question on SO and here is the link.

Comment: Point 2 obviously extends to other platforms than Twitter. On Facebook etc, there are obviously few restrictions on what you can post on your personal wall so your followers will see it, whereas groups you are a member of probably have explicit policies or moderators which you should probably consult before creating what may be perceived as an obnoxious or spammy post. The same goes for public IRC, Slack, Discord etc channels, as well as https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ rooms.