# If I'm not supposed to answer a question to bring it back to life, what should I do instead?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderation, bump

As you all know, not all questions are answered on Stack Overflow.

Once, I wrote 'Anyone interested in helping?' as an answer and moderators voted it down and warned me.

But sometimes it really helps for the question to be seen by the one that knows the answer? So shouldn't that be allowed for users? What about those lots of forgotten questions? The only chance for it to be answered then boils down to one's googling and finding it accidentally, which leaves the question so much time unanswered.

It makes me think if I expressed the question unclearly or in a confusing way. Should I remove the original post and reword it and ask it again?

Comment: Add a bounty...

Comment: So what is that voting down for? Pff, the title is not my intention, it's all about what it does and about seeking for an alternative to it to use the platform properly. You can't even tolerate that? Guys, it just puts users off here, really. I've heard from so many that they already know the answer for some questions but they don't feel like writing it as the community tends to vote everything down unconsciously.

Comment: You have expressed *this* question *"unclearly or in a confusing way"*. What are you actually trying to ask? Do you just want to know [How can I improve my questions or how to get more attention for my questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266338/3001761)

Comment: In my experience it's pretty rare that an answer gets downvoted, and even if it does you need 5 downvotes for every 1 upvote in order to loose precious internet points so those people who say they deliberately avoid answering questions because of downvotes are not very well informed.

Comment: Now that it's unclear and confusing or misleading, delete it. But what? I can't delete answered questions?! Things work a bit weird here. Don't all the rights of the content belong to the author? So much law violation and intolerance here. And I can't tolerate arrogance. One never learns if they never ask.

Comment: Totally absurd. How do I get my membership and every questions/answers removed here? If I cannot I'll have to consult my lawyer.

Comment: And you guys keeping voting down one another's posts. Oh goodness.

Comment: Downvotes on meta just mean disagreement. Since you haven't asked a cogent question and frankly you are just being silly (with the lawyer talk, lol), THAT'S why you are getting downvoted. As the first commenter said, this is what bounties are for. What you are asking for - we think, since you aren't actually clear when you write - is exactly why bounties were created. Please actually look at the site rules.

Comment: You got 14 downvotes on an MSO question and... you're leaving? *Seriously?* They're just downvotes; they're not some kind of personal attack. They are *certainly* not "law violation", "intolerance", or "arrogance".

Comment: @gnat this question is about unanswered questions and how to get them in front of a larger / the correct crowd. How does flagging an answer that it doesn't have can be a duplicate?

Comment: @rene this question is about whether it's appropriate to use blatant not-an-answer for whatever purpose. Answer to it is in the duplicate question: no it is not appropriate, such post will be flagged, deleted, and if user persists in such an abuse of the system they will be eventually answer banned. Note there is even a section called "'Bumping' the question" in the answer over there

Comment: @gnat No, the OP states they *tried* that and learned quickly that it wasn't the right way. So as they are desperate they turn to meta, explain what they tried (!) and how that didn't solve the issue. This doesn't mean this isn't an dupe but the one you chose is wrong if not misleading.

Comment: @rene per my reading "shouldn't that be allowed for users?" makes it about this kind not an answer. The other part of the question (rather implicit until [recent edit in rev 4](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/327993/revisions)) is covered in [What is the accepted method of renewing interest in a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303634/839601)

Comment: @gnat OK, agree on that, dupe hammered

Answer (score 13):

> Should I remove the original post and reword it and ask it again?

No. Edit it. That's what the edit button is for. Editing has the added benefit of bumping the question (though - if you over do it you will get warned).

Add details about what you tried, the things you have learned since you posted the question, any additional information you have. Clean it up, format it better.

If you have any comments asking for clarification - then edit clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If you edit a post, that also causes it to pop to the top of the stack. If your question has gone unanswered, is there more research you could do, edit the question and add it in? Or could you reword it?

The thing to remember about answers, they are answers and just that. They are not meant for bumping posts to the top. If we allowed that, people would get very confused who came across your question and couldn't understand how the term **bump** was considered an answer

[Stack Overflow has a few things you can do if your question goes unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you can reword the question to make it more clear, by all means, do it. An edit will 'bump' the question to the front page again, so people will see it. Just be careful: if there are (good) answers to your question already, you have to make sure they are still valid after your edit. And don't edit your question too often, people will get annoyed by that too and you might get a warning.

If, after editing it to a good question, you think it still doesn't get enough attention, place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it.